# HashMap<String, List<String[]>> извлечь List<String[]>

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, map

Добрый лень.
Есть метод, нужно получить данные в виде список массивов строк
из карты, где в данном виде хранятся значения.
подскажите пожалуйста.

```
private List<String[]> getDataFromParam(Report params) {    
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();;
    Map<String, List<String[]>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>(params.getOutFilesData()); // здесь приходят данные в виде Map<String, List<String[]>
    list.add(map.values());
    return list;
}
```

так не работает.

Comment: что за язык-то? Очевидно у тебя не работает, потому что `map.values()` не возвращает массив строк.

Comment: использую язык java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private List<String[]> getDataFromParam(Report params) {    
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();;
    Map<String, List<String[]>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>(params.getOutFilesData()); // здесь приходят данные в виде Map<String, List<String[]>
    //list.add(map.values()); add и addAll не поддерживается для возвращаемого типа Collection<V>
    // но можно пройти итератором по содержимому и добавить всё в list
    Iterator<List<String[]>> it = map.values().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        List<String[]> data = it.next();
        list.addAll(data);
    }
   return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) вернет **коллекцию** значение, а так как значения - это списки массивов строк, то будет получена коллекция списков массивов строк.

Из нее нужно получить обычный список массивов строк, для этого можно воспользоваться Stream Api и методом [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

```
List<String[]> list = map.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream) // на выходе Stream<String[]>
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // собираем Stream в список.
```