# Получить массив String[] из Map<String, String>

Tags: java, массивы, list, java-hashmap

Добрый день.
Есть такой метод.

```
private List<String[]> getData(Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> value) {
    List<String[]> list = null;
    Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>(value); // value содержит в себе данные в виде Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>
... 
return list; // List<String[]>
}
```

мне нужно получить `List<String[]>`, в котором бы лежали данные из значений `map`. По идее внутреннюю `Map(String, String)` мне нужно преобразовать в `string[ключ-значение]` и затем залить в `list`.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: добавь пример данных, которые ты передаешь и ожидаешь получить

Comment: в метод у меня передаются данные sql запроса. Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> value = new HashMap<>(); получить мне нужно содержание List<Map<String, String>, и перекомпоновать его в List<String[]>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) из [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/695024/186999), добавив преобразование `Map<String,String>` в `String[]`

Преобразование делается с помощью метода [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).

Для преобразование используем метод [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) получив набор пар ключ-значение, отображаем этот набор в набор строк, с помощью функции [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), и результат собираем в массив с помощью функции [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
List<String[]> list = map.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(q-> q.entrySet() 
              .stream()
              .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "-" + entry.getValue())
              .toArray(String[]::new)
        )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**[Пример работы на IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/tYJBgR)**

Comment: спасибо, сейчас почитаю про метод

Comment: да все работает, спасибо